# Django Foreignkey with edit fields and select field how to put in form

Tags: django, model-view-controller, inline-formset

I apologize if that question was raised before. But I have been struggling with this for weeks and couldn't find anything useful.

I have the following problem (it is simplified a lot but essentially my problem is presented)

I have a Model that has a lot of fields. It's called

```
class DocAide(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    pulse = models.DecimalField('Pulse', max_digits=3, decimal_places=0)
    weight = models.DecimalField('Weight (kg)', max_digits=3, decimal_places=0)
    bp_sys = models.DecimalField('BP Sys', max_digits=3, decimal_places=0)
    bp_dia = models.DecimalField('BP Dia', max_digits=3, decimal_places=0)
    temperature = models.DecimalField('Temp. deg C', max_digits=2, decimal_places=1)
    drugs = models.ManyToManyField(Drug, blank=True)    
    date = models.DateField(editable=False, default=timezone.now)
    doctors_notes = models.TextField('Patient is complaining about:', default='')
    note = models.TextField(max_length=100, default='')
```

The ForeignKey **Drugs** has Names of drugs with quantity I would like to have the possibility to select multiple drugs but with edit fields that show what dosage needs to be taken and when, it should be like a prescription. The Model looks like this:

```
class Drug(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    QUANTITY_STR = ['Bottle', 'Tablet' 'Injection', 'Capsules', 'other']
    QUANTITY = ((str, str) for str in QUANTITY_STR)
    quantity = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=QUANTITY, default='Bottle')
    category = models.CharField(max_length=150, default='')
    strength = models.CharField(max_length=150, default='')
    in_supply_stock = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    in_main_stock = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    date = models.DateField(editable=False, default=timezone.now)
    charge = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    morning = models.CharField(validators=[int_list_validator], max_length=3, default=0)
    midday = models.CharField(validators=[int_list_validator], max_length=3, default=0)
    evening = models.CharField(validators=[int_list_validator], max_length=3, default=0)
    night = models.CharField(validators=[int_list_validator], max_length=3, default=0)
    days = models.CharField(validators=[int_list_validator], max_length=3, default=0)
    tablets = models.CharField(validators=[int_list_validator], max_length=3, default=0)
```

How can I accomplish that in a form or template. I tried with Inlineformset it doesn't work. Also later I would like to have them preselected as well.

But for now I would like to have a button that produces a line with a dropdown list of the drugs and the edit fields of the model.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Before answering your question: ```drugs``` is a ```ManyToMany field```. Are you sure this is what you want? Your are talking about prescription and I would expect that the same drug does not have the same quantity etc on each prescription.

Comment: ManyToMany Field was chosen because a prescription can have many drugs such as Paracetamol and an Anitbiotic for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, a Drug object should not have a quantity associated with it, but a prescription "entry" should.

I think this is the Model structure you need:

```
QUANTITY_STR = ['Bottle', 'Tablet' 'Injection', 'Capsules', 'other']

class DocAide(models.Model):
    # same properties but remove `drugs` from this model


class Drug(models.Model):
    # same properties but remove `quantity` property


class Prescription(model.Model):
    drug = model.ForeignKey(to=Drug, related_name='prescriptions')
    doc_aide = model.ForeignKey(to=DocAide, related_name='prescriptions')
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    qty_container = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=QUANTITY_STR, default=QUANTITY_STR[0])
```

I changed a few things for you assuming I understood your business logic correctly. Such as how the `quantity` field works.

I created two fields to describe the quantity. `quantity` holds the numerical value, and `qty_container` holds the container's name if you will, like "Bottle", "Injection" and so on.

`qty_container` has a `max_length` equal to the number of characters in the word "Injection" since it is the largest word that might fit in this field. You had the `default` of that field be greater than the `max_length` which would cause an error.

Now I'm not sure why you wanted to save a tuple of two strings in the quantity field so I ignored that, but if you can comment on your intended logic here I might be able to edit the answer.

Anyway, the `Prescription` model.

This model will act as an intermediary between Drug and DocAide, and it is the one that will hold the quantity information. I've linked it with `Drug` and `DocAide` using foreign keys and set the `related_name` to suitable names. These "related_names" you'll find show up in the referenced model. So for example if you can do

```
doc_aide = DocAide.objects.get(pk=1)
for presc in doc_aide.prescriptions:
    print(presc.drug.name)
    print(presc.quantity)
```

This means that one `DocAide` object will be linked with one or many `Prescription` objects, each of those holds `quantity` info and is linked with a `Drug` object:

```
DocAide (id, etc) >> Prescription (doc_aide_id, drug_id, qty_info) >> Drug (id, etc)
```

As a side note, after you're sure everything works and you're good to go, you might need to look into query optimization in Django, because as it is written now, it's pretty unoptimized. But don't worry about optimization until you've finished and your code works correctly.

Comment: That sounds very plausible and to be honest I already started with this before I read your answer. I am happy to know that I was on the right path. But I will not take over the entire thing and then I will let you know what I got. Thanks

Comment: Hello bluegrounds, I am sorry for the late comeback. But I have tried your code in its entirety as much as I could apprehend. I have come across some problems. I hope you can help me with those. The problem is that the link between the models doesn't seem to be working. I am trying to access the prescriptions in the view but it doesn't have that attribute, it says?

Comment: No the form won't have that attribute but how can I access those entries in the view and save in the doc_aide model. Or is it the form data then. Another question then arises that if I have another form then I have to use the 2 forms in one template. How can that be done?

Comment: @AI I can't really help you without seeing the code. I suggest either editing the question above if the problem isn't too off-topic, or if it is, ask a new question and tell me to check it out. But here in the comments it's really difficult to provide any help.

Comment: You are right I am sorry, here is the new Q: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60467812/django-foreignkey-with-through-parameter Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

You likely want to move some fields of your `Drug` model to [an intermediary one that defines a foreign key to both your `Drug` and `DocAide` models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships).

This model should then be used as [the `through` option of your `DocAide.drugs` field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through).

If you are using the admin you'll be able to [rely on `inlines`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-models) to display an input form that allows selecting the desired `Drug` and annotating extra fields otherwise you'll likely have to build your own mechanism that [relies on `ModelFormSet`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets).

Comment: Ok thank you for your suggestion I will try that and let you know how I got on