# Django ForeignKey with through parameter

Tags: django, model-view-controller

Sorry the Title is wrong, I tried to change it but I can't. It doesn't mean 'through' parameter but 'to' parameter.

The following models make my code

```
class DocAide(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    pulse = models.DecimalField('Pulse', max_digits=3, decimal_places=0, blank=True, null=True)
    weight = models.DecimalField('Weight (kg)', max_digits=3, decimal_places=0, blank=True, null=True)
    bp_sys = models.DecimalField('BP Sys', max_digits=3, decimal_places=0, blank=True, null=True)
    bp_dia = models.DecimalField('BP Dia', max_digits=3, decimal_places=0, blank=True, null=True)
    temperature = models.DecimalField('Temp. deg C', max_digits=2, decimal_places=1, blank=True, null=True)

    prescriptions = models.ForeignKey(PrescriptionLine, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)        

    scans = models.ManyToManyField(Scan, blank=True)
    tests = models.ManyToManyField(LabTest,  blank=True)
    date = models.DateField(editable=False, default=timezone.now)
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(Doctor, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    no_charge = models.BooleanField('No Charge from Patient', default=False)
    doctors_notes = models.TextField('Patient is complaining about:', default='')
    part_to_scan = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='N/A', blank=True, null=True)
    part_to_xray = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='N/A', blank=True, null=True)
    note = models.TextField(max_length=100, default='')
```

and

```
class PrescriptionLine(models.Model):
    drug = models.ForeignKey(to=Drug, related_name='prescriptionlines', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    morning = models.CharField(validators=[int_list_validator], max_length=3, default=0)
    midday = models.CharField(validators=[int_list_validator], max_length=3, default=0)
    evening = models.CharField(validators=[int_list_validator], max_length=3, default=0)
    night = models.CharField(validators=[int_list_validator], max_length=3, default=0)
    days = models.CharField(validators=[int_list_validator], max_length=3, default=0)
    tablets = models.CharField(validators=[int_list_validator], max_length=3, default=0)
```

My Forms looks like this:

```
class DocAideForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Media:
        css = {'all': ('/static/admin/css/widgets.css',), }
        js = ('/admin/jsi18n/',)

    class Meta:
        model = DocAide
        fields = [  # 'no_charge',
                  'doctors_notes', 'scans', 'part_to_xray', 'part_to_scan', 'tests']
```

in view.py I have the inlineformset_factory

```
PrescriptionLineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(PrescriptionLine, DocAide, extra=1, fields=['drug', 'morning'])
```

With this construction the error comes "drug", "morning" unknown fields for DocAide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to access the `PrescriptionLine` objects connected to a `DocAide` object you'd have something like this

```
docaide = DocAide.objects.get(id=5)
for line in docaide.prescriptionlines:
    line.drug = Drug.objects.get(id=6)
```

I want to point out that a `DocAide` object is connected to a list of `PrescriptionLine` objects. Even if a particular `DocAide` object only has one `PrescriptionLine` linked with it, the `prescriptionlines` attribute will return a list, or a queryset to be exact.

And I want to draw your attention to `InlineFormsets`. I'm not sure if this is what you're asking about, but its good to know about them anyways. InlineFormsets enable you to add/edit PrescriptionLines to a DocAide object in the same page. The example code I give below will only apply to the admin site.

```
class PrescriptionLineInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = PrescriptionLine
    extra = 1

class DocAideAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [PrescriptionLineInline, ]

site.admin.register(DocAideAdmin)
```

This goes in the `admin.py` file and as I've said, it will only affect the admin site. This will create a section in the DocAide pages to add, edit, and delete PrescriptionLines directly.

To implement the same behavior in the front-end (outside the admin site), you'll have to edit your form class and use a `formset_factory`, or if you are working with a ModelForm (it seems like you are) you'd go with the easier `inlineformset_factory`.

If you do want to implement a formset in the front-end, I would suggest first implementing it in the admin site since it's easier, and you'll get a sense of how things fit together.

Here is the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets) page about Inline formsets.

Comment: @AI Did I understand your question correctly? I assumed this is what you were asking about.

Comment: Yes I think that is what I needed, I will try it now and I will let you. Thank you for your detailed description.

Comment: Ok I tried this and I am sorry for keep bothering you. But the inlineformset_factory isn't working. The Prescription isn't a Foreignkey and it misses that when using it. I can't use the through keyword in that case. Are you sure that this is the constellation that is correct here. Maybe I don't have to use the through keyword here?

Comment: `through` keyword? Where are you using the through keyword? Anyway, did you set up TabularInline fields in the admin site first as I suggested? Did it work in there? I don't understand what you mean by "The Prescription isn't a ForeignKey".

Comment: No I am sorry totally burned out here. I meant that the Prescription as not Model is not part of DocAide Model as a ForeignKey

Comment: Now I made it work, at least it is not failing with an error. I just have to create the entire form in the template. I hope that I can use your help again, you have been a great help so far. Thank you bluegrounds.

Comment: Hello bluegrounds, I have come back to the problem again after a long break. I think the solution is not right for what I am trying to do. I have a DocAide model and form from which I am trying to create a Prescription. I will solve it for now with a new page but my requirement is to have it all in one Form. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

To create form with inlilines, you must use the [inlineformset_factory](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/models/).
You can check an example of how to use it in the [official django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets).

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

views.py

```
from django.forms import inlineformset_factory
BookFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Author, Book, fields=('title',))
author = Author.objects.get(name='Mike Royko')
formset = BookFormSet(instance=author)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have to considered Django package `django-betterforms`?

You could use the `MultiModelForm` class to combine both models into one form containing two separate model forms.

Example:

```py
class DocAideForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Media:
        css = {'all': ('/static/admin/css/widgets.css',), }
        js = ('/admin/jsi18n/',)

    class Meta:
        model = DocAide
        fields = [  # 'no_charge',
                  'doctors_notes', 'scans', 'part_to_xray', 'part_to_scan', 'tests']

class PrescriptionForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = PrescriptionLine
        fields =# other fields from model 

class CombinedForm(MultiModelForm):
    form_classes= {
        'DocAideForm':DocAideForm,
        'PrescriptionForm':PrescriptionForm ,
    }
```

Documentation is here. https://django-betterforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/multiform.html

Comment: This would have been a great solution but during Implementation I ran into some problems. Which is why I have put this on hold for now. On one machine this code runs fine but on the other there is an ImportError.

Comment: @AI Cool, well give it a go when it's up and running! Are you familiar with virtual environments and GIT to manage package versions and source code between the machines? This should aid compatibility between machines.